# Is there any consensus or literature on the proportion of font parameters within plots?

Tags: data-visualization, references, descriptive-statistics, exploratory-data-analysis

This is now about how to make a plot, though that is the information that I'm finding when trying to search for an answer to my question. What I'm wondering, is whether there are any thoughts/literature on what the sizing of plotting parameters should be in relation to each other. Particularly, text sizing, though I'm happy to hear other thoughts (I feel that text sizing limits the scope of the question suitably though, perhaps linked literature will go further).

Some code to produce an example:

```py
def example():
    import itertools
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    labels = itertools.cycle(["Negative", "Positive", "Neutral"])
    colors = itertools.cycle(["red", "green", "blue"])

    # Font sizes
    title_fontsize = 12
    label_fontsize = 12
    legend_fontsize = 12
    axis_label_fontsize = 12
    footnote_fontsize = 12

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    np.random.seed(2)
    data = np.random.randint(1, 10, (3, 5))
    for d in data:
        color = next(colors)
        ax.plot(range(len(d)), d, zorder=-1, c=color)
        ax.scatter(range(len(d)), d, zorder=1, c=color)
        ax.scatter([], [], label=next(labels), s=label_fontsize, c=color)
    ax.yaxis.set_label("Some Response")
    ax.yaxis.set_label_text("Some Response", fontsize=axis_label_fontsize)
    ax.xaxis.set_label_text("Information", fontsize=axis_label_fontsize)

    box = ax.get_position()
    ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.7, box.height])
    handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    ax.legend(
        handles,
        labels,
        loc="center left",
        bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5),
        fontsize=legend_fontsize,
        frameon=False,
    )

    plt.suptitle("Emotion of Bats", fontsize=title_fontsize)

    ax.text(
        x=0, y=-0.12, s="This is information about the emotion of bats", fontsize=footnote_fontsize,
    )

    plt.savefig(
        "some_test.png", dpi=250, bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0.5,
    )

    plt.close()
```

Which creates the following image:

[image]

Here all text parameters have the same fontsize, `12`. It's pretty straightforward to conclude that enlargening the title might be useful, but how much? Is there a standard?

Increasing the title to `20` (all other code remains the same as the above)

```py
    # Font sizes
    title_fontsize = 20
    label_fontsize = 12
    legend_fontsize = 12
    axis_label_fontsize = 12
    footnote_fontsize = 12
```

gives the following:

[image]

I guess that's better?

I have also considered weighting things in terms of how important I feel they are, using something along the following:

```py
    # Font sizes
    title_fontsize = 20
    label_fontsize = title_fontsize * 0.5
    legend_fontsize = title_fontsize * 0.5
    axis_label_fontsize = title_fontsize * 0.6
    footnote_fontsize = title_fontsize * 0.4
```

Which gives:

[image]

At this point I have started looking for some solid opinions on the subject, and have been unable to find something.

## Suitable Answer

The answer does not have to be in Python or use the above code, that is just to illustrate the point. If there's a way that the fontsizes could me made a function of something such as the title, and literature to support the sizing of them, that would be appreciated.

Comment: @Tim it's absurd to close this without any explanation - unless you're suggesting that there's *no* literature that covers anything of this nature? There's a lot of stuff that's not 1+1=2 which is considered best practice, and it's perfectly reasonable to ask a question about it

Comment: This is not only matter of taste, but also depends on context, there’s no single answer. If you are looking for comprehensive resources on this subject, you should seek for some kind of courses on graphic design.

Comment: @Tim Given that there is an extensive literature in statistics and cartography on this subject--see Cleveland *et al.*, J. Bertin, and so on--there would seem to be ample evidence that this question may be relevant to the topics on CV.

Comment: Fair, I won’t oppose if anyone disagrees.

Comment: @Tim what's frustrating is I made the effort to provide good context for anyone who does know the material. It's been suggested that it's on topic from another mod, and seems so in the meta post I made too, why not open it?

Comment: Note: this question is being discussed on the [meta](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5920/62336).

Comment: I would say that the consensus is banal: (1) Text must be readable to be useful (2) If your purposes call for different emphases then font sizes in different titles or within a plot, might differ reasonably. (3) Fonts too large can be a bad idea too,.as if you are implying that the reader is stupid and needs you to shout (but plots designed for people with specific vision problems call for their own rules). (4)  Using more than about two different font sizes can seem over fussy. (5) Plots in papers and in presentations can differ.

Comment: Naturally if anyone disagrees with any of those points, there isn't a consensus and it is not banal.  I've written papers on statistical graphics (mostly focusing on Stata) and read (and reviewed) many books on statistical graphics, and I don't recall much discussion of this at all, beyond specific criticisms that plots are unreadable.  But there are always surprises you have not yet experienced.

Comment: @Nick There is cartographical literature about this. Dent's well-known textbook, *Cartography,* devotes a chapter to "The Intelligent Use of Typographics" in which he discusses type size, type families, letter and word spacing, legibility of type, lettering practices, the uses of capital and lowercase letters, and the placement of lettering, among others.  All these have applications to creating labels within and, to a certain extent, outside the plot area of any quantitative graphic.

Comment: @whuber Excellent point, but at the same time maps can be much more complicated than most statistical graphics. The kind of graphical example shown here -- and mine are never much different -- involve perhaps two or three kinds of text, say overall title, axis titles, extra annotation. I doubt that anyone will find reading through cartography texts and trying to distill the advice there more fruitful than making some rules for oneself and perhaps trying the results out on some captive readership.

Comment: err on the side of legibility, elder readers have trouble reading small fonts, so nothing should be smaller than 14

Comment: Not the question, but (1) your colours include red and green, but difficulty distinguishing those is common (2) you use solid circles for all 3 classes, so consider using different symbols (vital if your plot is reduced to monochrome) (3) direct labelling, i.e, placing explanatory text by each curve, and dropping the legend is often a good idea, although not necessarily in this example.